# Test if Hadoop is correctly working

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mahout

How can I now test my hadoop installation? I can't find adoop-examples-1.1.2.jar.
Is there any other way to test if Hadoop and Mahout are working correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the mapreduce hello world job. Note that your paths might be slightly different:

1. HADOOP_HOME is the dir, where you have hadoop installed.
2. exemplary test input file existing in `<HADOOP_HOME>/input/file01`
3. prepare dir structure in your hdfs:

   - `<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /wordcount`
   - `<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /wordcount/input`
   - `<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /wordcount/output`
4. put `file01` file into hdfs:

   - `<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/hdfs dfs -put <HADOOP_HOME>/input/file01 /wordcount/input`
5. go to the dir with examples jar:

   - `cd <HADOOP_HOME>/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib-examples` (in my case, the jar has name hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.3.0.jar)
6. fire away the mapred job `<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/hadoop jar ./hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.3.0.jar wordcount /wordcount/input/file01 /wordcount/output/file01-output`

The job should finish successfully, and you should see words from `file01` counted and stored in the /wordcount/output/file01-output dir

```
<HADOOP_HOME>/bin/hdfs -cat /wordcount/output/file01-output/part-r-00000
```

Comment: hadoop/bin/hdfs is an executable that performs different operations of the hadoop filesystem, it is not a directory. If you have no executable (shell script most likely) in bin dir, the name of the executable might be something different, but it must be there.

Comment: And I can see on your screenshot the hdfs script is in your directory, so it looks all right.

Comment: Use hadoop/bin/hdfs dfs -put to put a file to hadopp. Sorrt I made a mistake here is the example.

Comment: OK, thx. How can I access to the /wordcount/output/file01-output directory? I cant find it on my file system?!

Comment: You don't need to have /wordcount/output/file01-output existing. It will be created by the mapreduce job. Just make sure you have the /wordcount/output dir in hdfs

Answer (score 1):

First find the examples jar for hadoop using

`find /home -name hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar`

if it is present then see if "hadoop-core" jar is placed parallel to it or not. If both exist then follow the steps of simple word count through the site

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

if example and core jar is not present then download it and perform the same steps

Answer (score 0):

I would download the examples jar file or try to find it and run the Quasi Monte Carlo simulation.  That's probably the easiest to run and most straightforward to see if its working.

Just run a

```
find . -name *examples*
```

in your hadoop install directory.  Once you find that, just top your machines as it is running to see if they're getting the expected number of threads, load, etc.